# Objective-C: how can i change the alpha of uiimages created by a for loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, uiimage

I used a for loop to create several images and sliders on a scroller, how can I change the alpha of the images by changing the value of sliders? here is my code
I've tried to declare the uiimages outside the function loadImages, but I dont think this is a good idea.
I know how to do it without using for loop, but if I want to use for loop, how can I let the function know which uiimage it should operate on. Cause all the uiimages created in the for loop are not public objects I think.

```
-(void)loadImages
{

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //show drawing position in the output
    NSLog(@"x:%i, y:%i",xInc, yInc);
    //text label on the slider button
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78 + xInc, 55+yInc, 200, 20)];
    Person *thisPerson = [arrayOfPerson objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *namePerson = thisPerson.name;
    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",namePerson]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    //front office background image of slider
    NSString *frontimageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"frontofficeBUTTON.png"];
    UIImageView *frontimgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:frontimageName]];
    frontimgView.frame = CGRectMake(xInc, 10 + yInc, 332, 70);
    [frontimgView setTag:i];
    //back office background image of slider
    NSString *backimageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"backofficeBUTTON.png"];
    UIImageView *backimgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:backimageName]];
    backimgView.frame = CGRectMake(xInc, 10 + yInc, 332, 70);
    [backimgView setTag:i];
    //slider
    UISlider *slider=[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5+ xInc, 25+yInc, 322, 40)];
    //give a id tag to the slider
    [slider setTag:i];
    //set a action to the slider
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(UnlocklinkSlider:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //define the appearance of the slider
    UIImage *stetchLeftTrack= [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nothing.png"]
                               stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:30.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    UIImage *stetchRightTrack= [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nothing.png"]
                                stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:30.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [slider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"rightBUTTON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    yInc = yInc + 80;
    [_scrollView addSubview:backimgView];
    [_scrollView addSubview:frontimgView];
    [_scrollView addSubview:label];
    [_scrollView addSubview:slider];
}
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, scrollLength)];
}

- (void)UnlocklinkSlider:(UISlider*)slider 
{...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your slider should have a target and action added for `UIControlEventValueChanged` so that the image updates in sync (though it will work on touch up too). When you get the callback, use the slider tag to find the image view with the matching tag. Then set the image view `alpha` to `slider.value`.

---

To find the image view, you could loop over the subviews of the scroll view and check the tags of the subviews. You will want to change the tags from your current code as you have lots of things with the same tags.

A better option is to store references to the image views in an array property on your controller, then use the slider tag as the index in that array.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Yes it works, i use this to make the "unlock screen" animation for the slider.  [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(UnlocklinkSlider:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; this declare that the slider use the function UnlocklinkSlider. And in UnlocklinkSlider I add the animation code. All these work well. But I dont know how to find the image view the matching tag.

Comment: Ah, good idea. I'll try solving it with the array. Thanks a lot!